# Overriding d3 funnel chart's default

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have use the following link to create  a funnel chart with D3 :
[jakezatecky/d3-funnel](https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel)

The code works fine.
Now, as it said in tutorial, I want the block heights to be proportional to their weight so I need to change D3 deafult with:

```
D3Funnel.defaults.block.dynamicHeight = true;
```

but when I add tihs line to my code whole chart will be disappeared.

Whould you please help me find out the problem?
the code is :

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/0.3.2/d3-funnel.js?1"></script>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Create Chart">
<br><br>
<div id="funnelPanel">
    <div id="funnelContainer">
        <div id="funnel"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var data = [
        ["Clicked", "5,000"],
        ["Joined", "2,500"],
        ["Shared", "50"]
    ];

    width = $('#funnelPanel').width();

    var options = {
        width: width - 300,
        height: 400,
        bottomPct: 1 / 4,
        dynamicHeight: true,
        fillType: "solid",   // Either "solid" or "gradient"
        hoverEffects: true  // Whether the funnel has effects on hover
    };

    D3Funnel.defaults.block.dynamicHeight = true;

    var funnel = new D3Funnel(data, options);
    funnel.draw("#funnelContainer");

    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        var width = $("#funnelPanel").width();
        options.width = width;
        var funnel = new D3Funnel(data, options);
        funnel.draw('#funnelContainer');
    });
    $('#submit_btn').on('click', function () {
        var changed_data = [
            ["clicked", "3000"],
            ["joined", "70"],
            ["shared", "10"]
        ];
        var funnel = new D3Funnel(changed_data, options);
        funnel.draw('#funnelContainer');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: looks like outdated documentation to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antal Baye is right that you are using an outdated version of the library, but his answer is not quite right according to the latest documentation. You are using:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/0.3.2/d3-funnel.js

The latest version is the following:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/v0.7.0/d3-funnel.js

According to the latest documentation, you would construct your page as the following:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/v0.7.0/dist/d3-funnel.js"></script>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Create Chart">
<br><br>
<div id="funnelPanel">
    <div id="funnelContainer">
        <div id="funnel"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var data = [
        ["Clicked", 5000],
        ["Joined", 2500],
        ["Shared", 50],
    ];

    width = $('#funnelPanel').width();

    var options = {
        chart: {
            width: width - 300,
            height: 400,
            bottomWidth: 1 / 4,
        },
        block: {
            dynamicHeight: true,
            fillType: "solid",
            hoverEffects: true,
        },
    };

    var funnel = new D3Funnel("#funnelContainer");
    funnel.draw(data, options);

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        var width = $("#funnelPanel").width();
        options.width = width;

        funnel.draw(data, options);
    });

    $('#submit_btn').on('click', function() {
        var changed_data = [
            ["clicked", 3000],
            ["joined", 70],
            ["shared", 10],
        ];

        funnel.draw(changed_data, options);
    });
</script>
```

Note that some elements are contained under `chart` and others are contained under `block`. Further, note that `bottomPct` was renamed to `bottomWidth` a while ago. Lastly, note that the data array does not contain quotes around the value; a comma will be automatically added according to `label.format`.

See the JSFiddle example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lr613v/2/

Comment: Maybe the most important difference being that you are passing the data as a number value and his data is formatted as a "s,tring".  I have to think this would be a problem for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You use d3-funnel of v2.3.0, but it is already of v0.7.0. Data format was also changed along with funnel class constructor interface.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/master/dist/d3-funnel.js?1"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Create Chart">
<br><br>
<div id="funnelPanel">
    <div id="funnelContainer">
        <div id="funnel"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var data = [
        ["Clicked", 5000, "5,000"],
        ["Joined", 2500, "2,500"],
        ["Shared", 50, "50"]
    ];

    width = $('#funnelPanel').width();

    var options = {
        width: width - 300,
        height: 400,
        bottomPct: 1 / 4,
        dynamicHeight: true,
        fillType: "solid",   // Either "solid" or "gradient"
        hoverEffects: true  // Whether the funnel has effects on hover
    };

    D3Funnel.defaults.block.dynamicHeight = true;

    var funnel = new D3Funnel('#funnelContainer');
    funnel.draw(data, options);

    $(window).on("resize", function () {
    var width = $("#funnelPanel").width();
    options.width = width;
    var funnel = new D3Funnel('#funnelContainer');
    funnel.draw(data, options);
    });
    $('#submit_btn').on('click', function () {
        var changed_data = [
            ["clicked", 3000, "3000"],
            ["joined", 70, "70"],
            ["shared", 10, "10"]
        ];
        var funnel = new D3Funnel('#funnelContainer');
        funnel.draw(changed_data, options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @fafa71, In addition the options are all different in version 0.7 as well.  Also, you don't need to set this option globally you can do it in the options you pass in.  Here's a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/87gR3TN6bNhwlGOJkDsR?p=preview).

Comment: @Antal Baye thanke you so much. It works fine. you save my day.and about youre example, when I click on create chart, the chart disappeared.why?

Comment: @fafa71 'Create' button should work fine now - I forgot to change second data format at first.